# Action extensions - how will they be incorporated in my app?

Tags: ios, action, ios8, ios-app-extension

Will developers be required to add code to their app to incorporate Action extensions?

Let's say I developed an image editor for iOS - but I want to use Snapseed's Action extensions but not Instagram's. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No - The extension isn't an "extension" of your app. It's an extension of another app on the O/S the user has the option of utilizing given whatever context your app (the host app) is providing.

Think of it as the user getting to pick what they want to use, not you forcing them to use something. Plus, you have no control over what extension/app the user has installed on their device, so you cannot create a program to even try to depend on that.